# How can I add a savory note to (or otherwise improve) a sweet, cream based salad dressing?

Tags: flavor, salad-dressing

I recently purchased a cream based salad dressing and it is VERY sweet with an aftertaste, what can I add to make make it more savory and just make it taste better?

I love salad and my veggies are so sad with this dressing...

Comment: Cream based? As in dairy cream? How about a list of ingredients. Vinegar or lemon juice could usually help a too sweet dressing, but if it's really cream, it could cause it to curdle. Worcestershire sauce or anchovies would add savoriness.

Comment: If the dressing contains emulsifiers (as is frequently the case with mass produced dressings), then adding acid shouldn't curdle it. Look at the ingredients list for xanthan, lecithine or anything ending in "gum" and if it has it, try mixing a small portion with acid or lemon juice.

Answer (score 1):

Frequently the savory notes in a cream based salad dressing would be from a pungent cheese of some sort, like bleu or Parmesan. You could also try cutting some of the cream with buttermilk to reduce sweetness. Beyond that, it will really depend on what the rest of your ingredients are. Adding garlic powder or onion powder could also help depending on what flavor you're going for.

Answer (score 0):

A mild vinegar such as white wine or cider vinegar will reduce the sweetness. To increase the savoury element you'll need to add something rich in umami - I suggest parmesan or a similar hard cheese. As Jolenealaska mentioned, you could also add anchovies - do both and you're on your way to a Caesar dressing.